# How to pass an array from one page to another using PHP $_Post

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I want to know how I can send an array from one page to another using POST, but without an array?

Here is a small example of what I have:

```
<input type="text" name="url[]"  placeholder="URL Link"  />
```

On my first PHP page, (lets call it first.php), would I have this on top:

```
$_POST["url[]"];
```

And how would I catch that on my 2nd php page? (lets call that sec.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form was

```
<input type="text" name="url[]"/>
```

This is how you catch it.

```
$array = $_POST['url'];
```

It will return an array and will be saved in `$array`. Do note that your `$_POST` will hold several keys and one of them is another array so you won't be able to run functions like `array_map` and use `$_POST` as the targeted array

Comment: And what about passing it? Is my syntax correct? I'm not sure if I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: Yes, your syntax is correct. @user3108505

Comment: Last question, on the first.php, do I have to have it in php brackets(above the <html> tag)? Or should it be  in the html tags?

Comment: @user3108505 What do you mean exactly?

Comment: `$array = $_POST['url'];` goes in sec.php, not first.php. Put it wherever you want to use it, but yes, it does have to be in PHP brackets (`<?php` and `?>`), regardless.

Comment: I'm not talking about $array = $_POST['url']; ... I'm talking about $_POST["url[]"]; when you send it... Where do I put it in first.php? Above the html tags? in the html tags? - thanks

Comment: @user3108505 Why do you need to use `$_POST['url[]']`.. that is incorrect syntax..

Comment: That's what I'm asking. My first half of the question is how do I correctly pass it? (With out using a form)

Comment: @user3108505 "without using a form".. you didn't even mention that in your question.. you can't save input and process it without using a form..

Comment: a user below suggest session. Is that something different from a form or similar?

Comment: That's very different.. and you still need a form to get user input.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Btw, how do I pass it in first.php? Would it be $_POST['url[]'] ?? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: @user3108505 The correct syntax is found in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, variables parsed through forms like yours will be avaible through $_POST['x'];

You can either reteive values using the name as an index

```
$_POST['url']
```

Or if you have many variables it may be quicker to index them using the number they appear:

```
$_POST[i];
```

You could then use a for loop to access all the members of the array.

[PHP Manual: $_POST[]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

If you're looking to do this without a form as I saw you post,
Use the $_SESSION[] variable :)